# How to extract text from a specific table java apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a .doc document with three tables in it. Each table is slightly different and so the text has to be extracted differently. I am trying to do this using apache POI library  I would like to deal with each table with a different bit of code but I can't figure out how to do this as there doesn't seem to be a tableIndex as part of the apache POI. At the moment I am treating them the same as below but does anyone know how to specify a particular table:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "MyFile.doc";
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);  
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  

        Range range = doc.getRange();
        Paragraph para = range.getParagraph(0);

        String str="";

        TableIterator itr = new TableIterator(range);
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Table table = itr.next();
            for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.numRows(); rowIndex++){
                TableRow row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
                for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 1; colIndex++){
                    //Getting the first two cell text values out of the table
                    TableCell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
                    TableCell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
                    str= cell0.text()+" : "+cell1.text()+" : ";
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over them and keep track of the current index?

Comment: There is no way to specify a Table index though

Comment: Just track the current table index in a separate variable as you iterate through them as now - won't that do it?